# Add a small background for single line of text

Tags: html, css, web, styles

I am looking for a solution to this design. I have tried pseudo classes and `position: absolute` but it doesn't work for multiple lines of text.

The design I want:

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I downvoted because no attempt was made.

Comment: Sorry guys, here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1ahy3y1/7/. It only works for single line but not multiple lines. How can I make it with one heading only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use box-shadow for this:

```css
span {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: inset 0 25px 0 white, inset 0 -22px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

```html
<span>Hello!! How are you</span>
```